# Navigation Bar with centered Logo

Tags: html, css

I have searched through similar questions but found no solutions to what I am looking for specifically. I am trying to get my navigation bar around my centered logo, with an even number of links on either side of the logo. However, if the window is smaller, the links should appear below the logo. Basically I am trying to achieve the effect of this page: http://www.colbowdesign.com/index.html

Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
    <header>
            <img src="assets/CK-Square.png" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
            </ul>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
}

header li{
      display: inline;
}

header {
      width: 100%
      height: auto;
      border-style: solid;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
}
```

I appreciate any and all feedback/help!

Comment: Can you post your functioning code somewhere?

Comment: That website just floats left two of them and right two of them. You can just do the same, and use media queries to alter as you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is based on using media queries to change the layout from small screen up to desktop .

```
<header>
    <h2 id="logo">Logo</h2>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>


 header {
  width: 90%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

/* use media query to change the layout */
@media  (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .nav {
        margin-top: -42px;
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(1), .nav li:nth-child(2) {
        float: left;
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(3), .nav li:nth-child(4) {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

see it live http://jsbin.com/arexuq/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation and code. I will work on this when I return and let you know if I got it working myself! Thanks again!

Comment: @Micah That's great Micah, keep it up

Answer (score 1):

Add `li:nth-child` to your style

If you have four list, you can add this :

```
header li:nth-child(1), header li:nth-child(2) {
    float: left;
}
header li:nth-child(3), header li:nth-child(4) {
    float: right;
}
```

see on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/6rx8w/2/embedded/result/)

You should modify it a little to generate an attractive appearance, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/6rx8w/2/)

Answer (score -2):

Use table ..

```
<table><tr>
  <td><a href="#">Work</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">About</a></td>
    <td><img src="assets/CK-Square.png" class="logo"></td>  
  <td><a href="#">Contact</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">Social</a></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: But when the page width is decreased, it should move the logo to the center top and keep the links below.

Comment: You should not use table. You'll be yelled at by anyone who looks at it. Menus are not tabular data.