# Centering logo in nav bar

Tags: html, css, center

I have a hard time figuring out how to center my logo within the nav-bar with an uneven amount of links on each side.

I read about using `@media` queries with li:nth child in the CSS with floating properties to fix this, however I have not been able to.

Bear in mind that the Navigation links should be towards center of the screen and not the sides (unlike this: [Navigation Bar with centered Logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631178/navigation-bar-with-centered-logo)).

Here is my code:

```
<header>
<div id="navbar">

        <ul>

            <li><a href="#minigolf"><div id="minigolfdiv" class="navdiv">MINIGOLF</div></a></li>

            <li><a href="#bowling"><div class="navdiv">BOWLING</div></a></li>

            <li><a href="#arrangementer"><div class="navdiv">ARRANGEMENTER</div></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><div class="navdiv"><h2 id="logo">Funcity sport</h2></div></a></li>

            <li><a href="#priser"><div class="navdiv">PRISER</div></a></li>

            <li><a href="#aabningstider"><div class="navdiv">ÅBNINGSTIDER</div></a></li>

            <li><a href="#madogdrikke"><div class="navdiv">MAD & DRIKKE</div></a></li>

            <li><a href="#kontakt"><div class="navdiv">KONTAKT</div></a></li>

        </ul>

</div>
```

```
header{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:70px;
background-color:red;
}

#navbar{
display:inline-block;
height:70px;
width:auto;
float:left;
}

.navdiv{
height:100%;
width:100%;
padding: 0 10 0 10;
background-color:white;
border: 1px solid;
}

#logo{
background:url("media/logo.png") center no-repeat;
width:220px;
height:70px;
text-indent:-9999999999px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#minigolf, #bowling, #arrangementer, #priser,
#aabningstider, #madogdrikke{
height:1000px;
background-color:blue;
}

ul{
margin:0 0 0 40px;
padding:0 0 0 0;
list-style-type:none;
}

li{
display:inline-block;
height:70px;
background-color:white;
margin:0 0 0 0;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:70px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {

    .navdiv li:nth-child(1), .navdiv li:nth-child(2), .navdiv li:nth-child(3){
        float:left;
    }

    .navdiv li:nth-child(5), .navdiv li:nth-child(6), .navdiv li:nth-child(7),      li:nth-child(8){
        float:right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Completely unrelated, but instead of `<div id='navbar'>` you can use the `<nav>` element in HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code is semantic incorrect. A  (block element) cannot be wrapped in an  (inline element)

HTML:

```
<nav>
     <span>
          <a href="#minigolf">MINIGOLF</a>
          <a href="#minigolf">MINIGOLF</a>
     </span>
    <a href='logo' id="logo">logo</a>
     <span>
          <a href="#minigolf">MINIGOLF</a>
          <a href="#minigolf">MINIGOLF</a>
     </span>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav { 
width: 100%; 
position: relative; 
display: block; 
}
nav span { 
float: left; 
width: 50%; 
box-sizing: border-box;  
}
nav span:first-child { 
padding-right: 50px; /* half the logo width */ 
}
nav span:last-child { 
padding-left: 50px; /* half the logo width */ 
}
#logo { 
width: 100px; 
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
margin: auto; 
display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out relative positioning,

`#logo
{
position: relative;
top: 10px; // or any value you want.
}`

Or just upload an example at JSfiddle,Where I could see the actual problem.Instead of actual images just get div's constant width and heights.

Regards

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U76Mc/ here is a JSfiddle, a weird thing that happened after i added the media queries is the li on the far right, suddenly it is out of line with the others.

Comment: Its not weird at all, You set the width to 100% and give it a float:right,
If the screen-size isn't large enough the element is bound to go to the next line...For the solution to this problem try to give div's a %width instead of constant or display:none for a certain screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too wild, but what if you tried relative widths and gave the tree left hand side list items and the logo a width of approximately `50% / 3.5` each and the remaining four right hand side items a width of `50% / 4.5`?